# Select item from popup window and return the url to the parent window

Tags: 2007, javascript, popup, asseturlselector

I'm having a tricky problem which I can't solve with the AssetUrlSelector since it won't pass parameters. This code works except for the parameter:

```
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentProductCode" select="@Title" /> 

        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff32description{$Pos}" FieldName="NVPImage1" ControlMode="Edit"/>
          <PublishingWebControls:asseturlselector
                                DefaultOpenLocationUrl="~SiteCollection/assets/PublishedAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx?ProductCode={$CurrentProductCode}"
                                DefaultToLastUsedLocation="false"
                                DisplayLookInSection="false"
                                id="NVPImage1Selector"
                                UseImageAssetPicker="true"
                                runat="server"
                                OverrideDialogDescription="Images with product code: {$CurrentProductCode}"
                                AssetUrlTextBoxVisible="false">
            <xsl:attribute name="ClientCallback">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">function(returnedUrl) { SetURLFormField('spanNVPImage1', returnedUrl); }</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </PublishingWebControls:asseturlselector>
```

I need to make something simular myself: a popup that shows a catalog with a filter, user can select a thumbnail from the catalog, and the a callback function puts the URL in a form-field.

Via javascript `window.open` i can open the window, but I haven't got the selection/callback thing down yet..

Any advise is very welcome! (using MOSS2007)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Javascript, you can have the child window simply call a function in the parent and pass the selected value.

I have a project where we have a child popup with multiple drop-down and text boxes to filter search results. The desired records are checked and on OK click we pass the selected IDs to the parent by calling a JavaScript function and passing an array of the IDs.

It's been working well for us but we're using custom ASPX pages in the templates directory.